# How to show the newest post only

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

How can i show a list including the field `M.hID`, but only the newest `M.hID` depending on `M.tDate`?

```
SELECT  T.kId, T.tKode, M.hId, MAX(M.tDate) as newestTDate
FROM _PFaq T
JOIN _mUser M ON T.kId = M.kId AND T.tKode = M.tKode  
group by T.kId, T.tKode, M.hId, M.tDate
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is often approached as a *filtering* query rather than an *aggregation* query.  You want to join the tables and then filter so only the most recent row is maintained.

There are multiple different ways to do this, but a correlated subquery often has good performance:

```
select  T.kId, T.tKode, M.hId,M.tDate as newestTDate
from _PFaq T join
     _mUser M 
     on T.kId = M.kId and T.tKode = M.tKode 
where m.tDate = (select max(m2.tDate)
                 from _mUser m2
                 where m2.kId = M.kId and
                       m2.tKode = M.tKode
                );
```

That said, the two columns you are selecting are in both tables.  Unless you are using the `T` table for filtering, you don't even need the `JOIN`:

```
select M.kId, M.tKode, M.hId,M.tDate as newestTDate
from _mUser M 
where m.tDate = (select max(m2.tDate)
                 from _mUser m2
                 where m2.kId = M.kId and
                       m2.tKode = M.tKode
                );
```

The best index for this query is `_mUser(kId, tKode, tDate desc)`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `M.tDate` from group by

```
    SELECT  T.kId, T.tKode, M.hId, MAX(M.tDate) as newestTDate
    FROM _PFaq T
    JOIN _mUser M ON T.kId = M.kId AND T.tKode = M.tKode  
    group by T.kId, T.tKode, M.hId
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. By applying `row_number()` you can assign serial number to all the inserted `hID` in descending order for particular date. after that select the top record since that is last inserted as you needed.

```
; with cte as (
SELECT  row_number() over (partition by M.tDate order by M.hID desc) as Slno, T.kId, T.tKode, M.hId, MAX(M.tDate) as newestTDate
FROM _PFaq T
JOIN _mUser M ON T.kId = M.kId AND T.tKode = M.tKode  
group by T.kId, T.tKode, M.hId)
select T.kId, T.tKode, M.hId,  newestTDate from cte where slno = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

another way if support row_number() in your dbms

```
 select * from ( T.kId, T.tKode, M.hId, M.tDate as newestTDate,row_number()over(partition by M.hID order by M.tDate desc) rn  from
 FROM _PFaq T
    JOIN _mUser M ON T.kId = M.kId AND T.tKode = M.tKode
              ) a where a.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want `M.hId` as the field to group some rows with and search maximum value of `M.hId` between each group, then you should just group by `M.hId`:

```
SELECT  T.kId, T.tKode, M.hId, MAX(M.tDate) as newestTDate
FROM _PFaq T
JOIN _mUser M ON T.kId = M.kId AND T.tKode = M.tKode  
group by M.hId
```

Comment: and what about: `T.kId, T.tKode`. don't you think that these columns are required in `GROUP BY` clause as they are included in `SELECT` clause in your example

Comment: It's not a rule that all fields in `SELECT` clause have to participate in `GROUP BY` clause. at least in MySQL it isn't. however maybe you are right because the OP have used them in his snippet so they may have an important role there. @Tejash